# style ::-webkit-slider-thumb with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have some sliders which I want to style via jquery
For example:

```
<input type="range"/>
```

To style it with plain css I would write:

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
/* blah blah blah*/
background:red;
}
```

This is working.
However if I try this:

```
$("input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb").css("background","red");
```

It will not give me an error but it also will not work.
I have seen some other similar questions .The answer to these questions were to insert a new style tag with jquery and some classes(Something i don't want to do).Is there any way to style ::-webkit-slider-thumb with jquery?
UPDATE
I don't want to inject any new style tags to my html or use custom classes!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CSS

```
.redslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('input[type=range]').addClass('redslider');
```

### Why?

`::-webkit-slider-thumb` isn't actually a selector. It's like setting an `:active` through a style attribute which isn't possible. That makes it so we have to make it in a class and add it. You could use `document.styleSheets` but that is ambiguous, complicated, and is overkill for a simple task such as this

Answer (score 6):

Plain JavaScript could work for this:

```
for(var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[1].rules.length; j++) {
    var rule = document.styleSheets[1].rules[j];
    if(rule.cssText.match("webkit-slider-thumb")) {
        rule.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
}
```

**[Here is an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cz5s1rgL/6/)**

---

Because `::-webkit-slider-thumb` is *pseudo-element* jQuery cannot select it, which leaves you with limited options to style this.

---

You could optionally use jQuery:

```
$("input[type='range']").addClass('slideThumb');
```

and then using CSS add:

```
.slideThumb::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   background: red;
}
```

but this would be equivalent of simply adding the class directly onto your input:

```
<input class="slideThumb" type="range"/>
```