# Set the slider thumb height with variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set using jquery the **height property** of range input. I came across a lot of answers that says that it is directly not possible, and you need to do a workaround , here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555258/set-webkit-scrollbar-thumb-visibility-in-jquery), or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475024/style-webkit-slider-thumb-with-jquery)

**CSS :**

```
input[type="range"]::webkit-slider-thumb {
      height : 15px;
}
```

The workaround proposed is to add another css class with new height for instance :

```
.newHeight::webkit-slider-thumb {
      height : 45px;
}
```

and finally you can set the new `height` by adding (or toggle) the new class :

**JQuery :**

```
$('html').addClass('newHeight');
```

This is working fine, but my problem is that the new `height` should be variable in my case; I don't have the exact value, it is computed based on other parameters on page load. So is it possible to set in this case the `height` of the `slider-thumb` ?

Comment: _it is computed based on other parameters on page load_ -- What parameters?

Comment: it is actually based on the parent container size, and the parent container is resizable.

Comment: what percentage of height of the parent should the element get?

Comment: Based on input height it should change right and you just mentioned `45px` right. Change that to `80%`

Comment: Question little bit not clear. Reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set/get the height of an element by using JQuery[`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Setting height

```
$('your_selector').height(50);
```

Getting height

```
$('your_selector').height();
```

Get the parent element height of the input range and set the thumb height 80% of it

Here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0hGlsrTWtuVyDeRy8h6u?p=preview)

Basically, by changing `width` of the element you can change the `height` of the thumb. I just mentioned `5%`. In css file of the plunker **/* SET HEIGHT */** find that comment. You can change there

Comment: the range input has height of 0px but the slider thumb no, if you set the height to 80% for instance it will take 80% of 0px so the slider will have height of 0px

Comment: I want to set the height of the slider thumb to 80% of the parent of the input range

Comment: how can I set the height to 80% of the slider thumb with jquery ?

Comment: it is a webkit-slider-thumb, you can not access it with jquery, that's my problem

Comment: here is mine https://plnkr.co/edit/d462UvF2FF54V1HHEt6U?p=preview height is set to 150px; if you set height to 80% on the css file, the slider will disappear